# Creating role requirement for accessig a webpage with Spring BOOT

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to add to website I created a requirement for user to be logged-in in order to access content and also split 3 types of users: non logged-in person, admin and standard user. I struggle a lot with it as I was unable to find a guide that would both explain it to me and work properly at the same time. Could you guys please help me and tell em what am I doing wrong? I spent 6 days trying to get this logging in feature to work and I feel compleatly lost at this point because I tried so many different codes and approaches from guides I found. As for my database I am using SQL Workbench.

The problem is (at least I think this is the problem) that in SecurityConfig in configure method I am not actually passing Role of the User (hasAnyRole('Admin')). I was trying to do it in many ways but I don't really udnerstand how am I supposed to pass Role to it.

Here is my controller package:

MainController:

```
package Projekt.ProjektAI.controller;

import Projekt.ProjektAI.entities.Book;
import Projekt.ProjektAI.service.BookService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.security.Provider;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    private BookService service;

    @Autowired
    public MainController(BookService service){
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String viewNormalHomePage(Model model) {
        List<Book> listBooks = service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("listBooks", listBooks);
        return "indexNormal";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    public String viewAdminHomePage(Model model) {
        List<Book> listBooks = service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("listBooks", listBooks);
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public String viewUserHomePage(Model model) {
        List<Book> listBooks = service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("listBooks", listBooks);
        return "indexStandard";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin/new")
    public String showNewBookPage(Model model) {
        Book book = new Book();
        model.addAttribute("book", book);

        return "newBook";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView showEditBookPage(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("editBook");
        Book book = service.get(id);
        mav.addObject("book", book);

        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveBook(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book) {
        service.save(book);

        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteBook(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {
        service.delete(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model) {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userIndex() {
        return "user/index";
    }
}
```

UserRegistrationController:

```
package Projekt.ProjektAI.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import Projekt.ProjektAI.service.UserService;
import Projekt.ProjektAI.registrationDTO.UserRegistrationDTO;
import Projekt.ProjektAI.entities.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class UserRegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public UserRegistrationDTO userRegistrationDto() {
        return new UserRegistrationDTO();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        return "registration";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid UserRegistrationDTO userDto,
                                      BindingResult result) {

        User existing = userService.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail());
        if (existing != null) {
            result.rejectValue("email", null, "There is already an account registered with that email");
        }

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.save(userDto);
        return "redirect:/registration?success";
    }
}
```

Entities package:

Book entity:

```
package Projekt.ProjektAI.entities;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String autor;
    @Column
    private String tytul;
    @Column
    private String gatunek;
    @Column
    private float cena;

    public Book() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", autor='" + autor + '\'' +
                ", tytul='" + tytul + '\'' +
                ", gatunek='" + gatunek + '\'' +
                ", cena=" + cena +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Role entity:

```
package Projekt.ProjektAI.entities;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    protected Role() {}

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Role{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

User entity:

```
package Projekt.ProjektAI.entities;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))

    private Collection <Projekt.ProjektAI.entities.Role> roles;

    public Collection <Projekt.ProjektAI.entities.Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection <Projekt.ProjektAI.entities.Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + "*********" + '\'' +
                ", roles=" + roles +
                '}';
    }
}
```

registration DTO package:

FieldMatch interface:

```
package Projekt.ProjektAI.registrationDTO;

import javax.validation.Payload;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Target({
        TYPE,
        ANNOTATION_TYPE
})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = FieldMatchValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface FieldMatch {
    String message() default "{constraints.field-match}";
    Class < ? > [] groups() default {};
    Class < ? extends Payload > [] payload() default {};
    String first();
    String second();

    @Target({
            TYPE,
            ANNOTATION_TYPE
    })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {
        FieldMatch[] value();
    }
}
```

Field Match Validator:

```
package Projekt.ProjektAI.registrationDTO;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

public class FieldMatchValidator implements ConstraintValidator <Projekt.ProjektAI.registrationDTO.FieldMatch, Object > {

    private String firstFieldName;
    private String secondFieldName;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final Projekt.ProjektAI.registrationDTO.FieldMatch constraintAnnotation) {
        firstFieldName = constraintAnnotation.first();
        secondFieldName = constraintAnnotation.second();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Object value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        try {
            final Object firstObj = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, firstFieldName);
            final Object secondObj = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, secondFieldName);
            return firstObj == null && secondObj == null || firstObj != null && firstObj.equals(secondObj);
        } catch (final Exception ignore) {}
        return true;
    }
}
```

User Registration DTO:

```
package Projekt.ProjektAI.registrationDTO;


import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Projekt.ProjektAI.registrationDTO.FieldMatch.List({
        @Projekt.ProjektAI.registrationDTO.FieldMatch(first = "password", second = "confirmPassword", message = "The password fields must match"),
        @Projekt.ProjektAI.registrationDTO.FieldMatch(first = "email", second = "confirmEmail", message = "The email fields must match")
})
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserRegistrationDTO {
    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    private String confirmPassword;

    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;

    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    private String confirmEmail;

    @AssertTrue
    private Boolean terms;
}
```

repositories package:

Book Repository

```
package Projekt.ProjektAI.repositories;

import Projekt.ProjektAI.entities.Book;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
}
```

User Repository:

```
package Projekt.ProjektAI.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import Projekt.ProjektAI.entities.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository < User, Long > {
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

security package:

```
    package Projekt.ProjektAI.security;

import Projekt.ProjektAI.entities.User;
import Projekt.ProjektAI.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import Projekt.ProjektAI.service.UserService;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/new", "/edit/{id}", "/save", "/delete/{id}")
                .access("hasAnyRole('Admin')")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/registration**","/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
}

service package:

Book Service:

    package Projekt.ProjektAI.service;
    
    import Projekt.ProjektAI.entities.Book;
    import Projekt.ProjektAI.repositories.BookRepository;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Service
    public class BookService {
    
    
        private BookRepository repo;
        @Autowired
        public BookService(BookRepository repo)
        {
            this.repo =repo;
        }
    
        public List<Book> listAll() {
            return repo.findAll();
        }
    
        public void save(Book book) {
            repo.save(book);
        }
    
        public Book get(long id) {
            return repo.findById(id).get();
        }
    
        public void delete(long id) {
            repo.deleteById(id);
        }
    }

User Service interface:

    package Projekt.ProjektAI.service;
    
    import Projekt.ProjektAI.registrationDTO.UserRegistrationDTO;
    import Projekt.ProjektAI.entities.User;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    
    public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService {
    
        User findByEmail(String email);
    
        User save(UserRegistrationDTO registration);
    }
```

User Service Implementation:

```
package Projekt.ProjektAI.service;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import Projekt.ProjektAI.service.UserService;
import Projekt.ProjektAI.registrationDTO.UserRegistrationDTO;
import Projekt.ProjektAI.entities.User;
import Projekt.ProjektAI.entities.Role;
import Projekt.ProjektAI.service.UserService;
import Projekt.ProjektAI.registrationDTO.UserRegistrationDTO;
import Projekt.ProjektAI.repositories.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public User save(UserRegistrationDTO registration) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName(registration.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(registration.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(registration.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registration.getPassword()));
        user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(new Role("ROLE_USER")));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),
                user.getPassword(),
                mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
    }

    private Collection < ? extends GrantedAuthority > mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection < Role > roles) {
        return roles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

application properties:

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3366/projektai?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin

Thank you very much for any tips!

Comment: Hi, take a look at https://dzone.com/articles/securing-spring-data-rest-with-preauthorize

Comment: you posted a lot of code but you have not written what your actual problem is all you write is: `I spent 6 days trying to get this logging in feature to work` but you have not written a single line that says what is actually not working. What your error message is, your logs? What you expect, and what you get etc. Voted to close

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The problem is that for some reason I can access indexNormal via "localhost:8080/", but when I try to access admin login via "localhost:8080/admin/login" it returns me error and same with user login

Comment: a lot of code to look at... as far that I can see you have `@RequestMapping(value = "/login"` for your login ?... But you configured `.loginPage("/admin/login")`

Comment: You are correct, I changed that but while I can now access the login page I still cannot login to my admin account that is saved in database because when I try it sends me to whitelabel error page instead of "/admin" or "/user" (depending on account I choose)

Comment: dont write your problem here, update your question with your problem, and your logs with the problem. not `it returns me error ` yes, but WHAT error? post the LOGS

Comment: Okay sorry again, I updated the question and code. I am trying to fix the problem my self but I think I'm not smart enougth for this. Please read the problem paragraph at the beggining.

Comment: Ankit Sharma I tried doing it that way but I don't understand how is that useful for my case as I don't want to put authorisation requirement on the whole repository just on some methods like adding new book (tried to achieve that by giving authorisation requirement on pages like /new etc.)